# Why would C get stuck halfway through a while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop

When I compile and run this code (it's part of a much larger program), Linux gets halfway through the `while` loop, then simply stops working.

The code below prints `time: 0` and then hangs, doing nothing else until I suspend the process. Why on earth would it print `time: 0` but not the following line of sanity check?

```
while (i < 5)
{
    printf("time: %d\n",elapsedTime);
    printf("sanity check");
    foo();
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Output usually is buffered and only written after a flush or newline. In

```
printf("sanity check");
```

there is no newline, so if you run in an endless loop after this, you won't see it.
Replace it with

```
printf("sanity check\n");
```

or

```
printf("sanity check");
fflush(stdout);
```

and you'll see it.

Comment: Oh good. I was worried about the  function, but I thought I wasn't even reaching it. Now that I know that I *am*, I can continue to debug. Thanks!. I'll accept the answer in 10 min. when I can.

Comment: @Raven: Had you used a debugger to debug (the clue is in the name), you'd have known it had got that far, and probably why it was ultimately failing (in foo() no doubt).

Comment: @Clifford - yup. I've been spoiled with Visual Studio and C# development. Unfortunately, I can't get VS to handle a plain C environment, so I'm stuck with JEdit alone.

Comment: @Raven: But you said you were developing on Linux, use GDB or a GDB front end such as Insight or KDevelop on Linux.  Getting Visual C++ to compile C code is trivial.  All that is required is to name the sources with a .c extension. Don't let the fact that "add new item" does not offer C file as a type throw you, just ignore the defaults offered and type *filename*.c in the filename box, and you are good to go.  I also suggest that you start your project using the "Empty Project" template, so that it does not generate any C++ or C++/CLI template code for you.

Comment: @Clifford - whoops. That was suppposed to be GEdit, not JEdit. I'll look into that, thanks.