# Why might Python break down halfway through a loop? TypeError: __getitem__

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, nonetype

**The Goal**

I have a directory with 65 .txt files, which I am parsing, one by one, and saving the outputs into 65 corresponding .txt files. I then plan to concatenate them, but I'm not sure if jumping straight to that might help find a solution here.

**The Problem**

I am receiving:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

and have seen two similar threads:

[TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907949/typeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-getitem)

[Python: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322402/python-typeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-getitem)

My problem seems somewhat strange, however, as it **does manage** to go through the input files, parsing them and writing the output file about ten times, at which point I get the error. The files are all similar, just HTML source code from website (i.e. the same website, just different pages of it, and so the same basic HTML structure).

Here is the function where the error occurs; in the last line of this snippet:

```
def parse(elTree):
    desired_value = elTree.xpath('my_very_long_xpath')
    desired_value = [x.get('title')[8:] for x in desired_value]
```

I do have a few more variants of these - I am actually parsing for about 5 to 6 different `desired_value`s. And all of this is simply running inside of a larger loop where the files are read in to the `parse` function and then the output is written to a new file.

**What I have tried**

I have removed the file where I initially got the error, but the same error occurred at the next file. I did the same again, removing two files, but still getting that error.

I introduced a `time.sleep(3)` between each file, just to allow things to maybe run more smoothly. I realized there may be a buffer for the whole process, which is maybe being read and it is just being wiped, and so there is no file there... Here is a similar [occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124769/why-would-c-get-stuck-halfway-through-a-while-loop) within a loop in `C`. Unfortunately the sleep for 3 seconds (plus then scattered around at various other points) didn't help me. the code fails at exactly the same point.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError), a `TypeError` arises when a function is applied to an object of inappropriate type, so how can it be that it is occurring after functioning correctly 10 or 11 times?
Here is more official [information](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) regarding the `__getitem__` method

As the code does work well otherwise, I haven't included the rest, but if someone suspects it may originate from somewhere else, with good reason, then I will add more of the code.

I have inspected the contents of the .txt files for those that worked and those where it failed and the xpaths work in both, the contents **are** there to be found and parsed.

I used the code on 30 copies of the same file, which did execute successfully, so there must be subtle differences in the HTML code, which my parser is not recognizing.

Comment: `x.get('title')` is returning `None`

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the standard reply, as can be seen in the three links i provided. The questions is **why**, when it has already managed to go through 10 or so of the 65 files? It doesn't seem to depend on the actual file, as I also mentioned in my OP.

Comment: To expand on what @PeterWood is saying -- the `get` method is looking for a `title` attribute, and the input data might not have it. This is not a python problem -- you need to figure out if all your data looks like how you expect it to, and update your code accordingly.

Comment: Catch the exception and print it. See what `x` is. It will have an element which matches the xpath, but doesn't have an attribute `'title'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` means that you attempted to use some kind of indexing, like `mylist[2]`, on `None` instead of on something like a `list`. This means that the internal call to that object's `__getitem__` failed, because `None`, which is an object of type `Nonetype`, doesn't have such a method defined for it.

The problem is in `x.get('title')[8:]`: the `get()` method didn't find any key called `'title'` in `x`, so it returned `None`. However, you then try to slice it with `[8:]`. If it had returned a `list` or similar object it would work fine, but not so with `None`.

I recommend introducing some kind of error handling:

```
try:
    desired_value = [x.get('title')[8:] for x in desired_value]
except TypeError:
    return
```

You will have to correct and expand this stub to make it behave in a way that's appropriate for your program. Maybe instead of a `return` statement you'll need to define some kind of default `desired_value` or something.

Comment: I will give this a go, and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

`x.get('title')` is returning `None`.

If you want to filter the list comprehension, without repeating the query, you can build a single item list from the query result and filter it if it's `None`:

```
desired_value = [title[8:] for x in desired_value
                 for title in [x.get('title')]
                 if title]
```

Comment: I will give this a go, and get back to you!