# Scraping and parsing with Python - lxml with long Xpaths

Tags: python, lxml

I am loading and scrolling on dynamically loading pages. An example is the Facebook "wall", which only loads the next items once you have scrolled to somewhere near the bottom.

I scroll until the page is veeeery long, then I copy the source code, save it as a text file and go on to parsing it.

I would like to extract certain parts of the webpage. I have been using the [lxml module](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#using-xpath-to-find-text) in python, but with limited success. On there website they only show examples with pretty short Xpaths.

Below is an example of the function and a path that gets me the user names included on the page.

```
usersID = elTree.xpath('//a[@class="account-group js-account-group js-action-profile js-user-profile-link js-nav"]')
```

this works fairly well, however I am getting some [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833183/why-might-python-break-down-halfway-through-a-loop-typeerror-getitem) (another post of mine), such as:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getitem'
```

I have also been looking at the Xpaths that Firebug provides. These are of course much longer and very specific. Here is an example for a reoccuring element on the page:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ol[1]/li[26]/ol/li/div/div[2]/p
```

The part towards the end `li[26]` shows it is the 26th item in a list of the same element, which are found at the same level of the HTML tree.

I would like to know how I might use such firebug-Xpaths with the lxml library, or of anybody knows of a better way to use Xpaths in general?

Using example HTML code and tools [like this](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) for test purposes, the Xpaths from Firebug don't work at all. Is that path just ridiculous in people's experience?

Is is very specific to the source code? Are there any other tools like Firebug that produce more reliable output for use with lxml?

Comment: Python's lxml's `xpath()` is a full XPath 1.0 query processor. So both paths you show are allowed. Your error means there is no value at that particular path -either no actual data or path does not exist. Using `//` in xpath references exact absolute location (i.e., shortcut) while `/` requires the full path relative to the root node.

Comment: Is there a robust way of using regex-like symbols in the Xpaths, like adding a `*` to get all data on a path or from a certain level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two things which, together, worked very well for me.

**The first thing:**

The lxml package allows the usage of some functions in combination with the Xpath. I used the [`starts-with`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAtFDeux2x8) function, as follows:

```
tweetID = elTree.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'the-non-varying-part-of-a-very-long-class-name')]")
```

When exploring the HTML code (tree) using tools such as Firebug/Firepath, everything is shown nice and neatly - for example:

*

[image: Xpath and class name in Firebug]

*

When I used the highlighted path, i.e. `tweet original-tweet js-original-tweet js-stream-tweet js-actionable-tweet js-profile-popup-actionable has-cards has-native-media with-media-forward media-forward cards-forward` - to search my elTree within the code above, nothing was found.

Having a look at the actual HTML file I was trying to parse, I saw it was really spread over many lines - like this:

[image: Actual HTML code]

this explains why the lxml package was not finding it according to my search.

**The second thing:**

I know is not generally recommended as a workaround, but the Python approach that it is "easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" applied in my case - The next things I did was to use the python [`try` / `except`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) on a TypeError that I kept getting at seemingly arbitrary lines of my code

This may well be specific to my code, but after checking the output on many cases, it seems as though it worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

FireBug actually generates really poor xpaths. They are long and fragile because they're incredibly non specific beyond hierarchy. 
Pages today are incredibly dynamic.

The best way to work with xpath on dynamic pages is to locate common elements as the hook and perform xpath ops from those as your path root. 
What I mean here by common elements is stable structural elements that are highly likely or guaranteed to be present. Pick the one closest to your target in terms of containment hierarchy. Shorter paths are faster and clearer.

From there you need to create paths that locate some specific unique attribute or attribute value on the target element. 
Sometimes that's not possible so another strategy is to target the closest uniquely identifiable container element then get all elements similar to yours under that and iterate them looking for your goal.

Highly dynamic pages require sophisticated and dynamic approaches.

Facebook changes a lot and will require script maintenance frequently.

Comment: Good advice, thanks! Do you happen to have any Twitter-specific knowledge/experience?